# Binance Api Python setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, binance, pep517

I created a Bot to trade BTC with Binance and am currently trying to set my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ up. With every pip install python-binance I get

```
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ubuntu/test/venv/bin/python3 /tmp/tmp6c7k6imv build_wheel /tmp/tmpuge_0m5b
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cje139s6/backports.zoneinfo
  Complete output (39 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports
  copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports
  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  running egg_info
  writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
  warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
  writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/backports/zoneinfo
  running build_ext
  building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/lib
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/test/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
  lib/zoneinfo_module.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      1 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I tried to update pip, wheel, setuptools to the newest version, ran the same command on my desktop computer, where it worked without problem.
The systeminformation for my Raspberry Pi are:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Python: 3.8.10
- pip: 20.0.2
- wheel: 0.37.0
- setuptools: 58.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I ran `sudo apt install python3-dev` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my Raspberry Pi. Use `pip3  install python-binance` instead of `pip install python-binance`

Answer (score 0):

I Faced this problem in past and had post about it but this is direct solution.

#### Details

The issue is mostly related to retrieving data from OS About Current Time With IANA And `backports.zoneinfo` is pre-builted for Windows And We Have to Build The Package For Linux Or MacOS With Ruby Compiler Or Any Other Language Specified By Error Also.

#### First Solution

Upgrade the `pip` with `wheel` and Try Again Installing.

```sh
pip install --upgrade pip wheel

pip install backports.zoneinfo
```

#### Second Solution

Try Installing the Alternative Package Named `tzdata`. ( Worked for My `fastapi` project. )
The Package Supports Python 3 But It's Readme Is Not Updated About the Python 2 Support By Dev IDK Why .

```sh
pip install tzdata
```

#### Third Solution

Install `Ruby Compiler` From Your System Package Manager and Run The pip code again.
Given Below is for `Ubuntu`.

```sh
sudo apt-get install ruby-full

pip install backports.zoneinfo
```